# Tableview crashing

Tags: iphone, xcode, arrays

I´m retrieving data from core data into 2 arrays.

```
-(void)loadData{

AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.managedObjectContext;

   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityLocation = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Devices" inManagedObjectContext:context];
fetchRequest.entity = entityLocation;


NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"location = %@",actuallLocationName];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray *temp = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"matches in hostArray = %d",[temp count]);


hostArray = [temp valueForKey:@"hostname"];
deviceArray = [temp valueForKey:@"devicename"];

[myTable reloadData];
}
```

in my UITableView i have 2 section --section 0 with 2 different customcells, and section 1 to show data form the array(s)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (section == 0) {
    return 2;
}
       return [hostArray count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CustomCell = @"CustomCell";
   static NSString *CustomCell1 = @"CustomCell1";
   static NSString *CustomCell2 = @"CusrtomCell2";

UITableViewCell *cellA = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCell1];
if (cellA == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SettingCellHost" owner:self options:nil];
    cellA=hostNameCell;
    self.hostNameCell=nil;
}

UITableViewCell *cellB = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCell2];
if (cellB == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SettingCellDevice" owner:self options:nil];
    cellB=deviceNameCell;
    self.deviceNameCell=nil;
}

UITableViewCell *cellC = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCell];
if (cellC == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DefaultCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cellC=defaultCell;
    self.defaultCell=nil;
}
if ([hostArray count] != 0) {
    [defaultCellLabel setText:[hostArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}



if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return cellA;
    }
}

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        return cellB;
    }
}


return cellC;
}
```

after start app is crashing with

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI       objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

but the array(s) are not emtpy

```
2012-05-27 18:10:39.010 TabWithCore[7249:fb03] Array 1 is (
1234567
) and Array 2 is (
Host
)
```

the strange is, when i change the value numberofrows for section 0  from 2 --> to 1, all works fine...

Comment: Here I posted my answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of code is executed without checking which Section you are in. So when section is 0 (2 rows) and indexPath.row is 1, this throws an exception as it tries to access hostArray[1] whereas it has just 1 value.

```
if ([hostArray count] != 0) {
    [defaultCellLabel setText:[hostArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

To fix this, check for the section before you execute any of this code. Something like the following will work.

```
if (indexPath.section == 1)    
{
    UITableViewCell *cellC = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCell];
    if (cellC == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DefaultCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cellC=defaultCell;
        self.defaultCell=nil;
    }
    if ([hostArray count] != 0) {
        [defaultCellLabel setText:[hostArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    return cellC;
}
```

Comment: thx chirag, thats it! spend so many hours in this problem, and it was so simple :-)

Answer (score 0):

your array has only one object in it... and you are trying to set two cells from that. So when it tries to access the second object of the array it crashes since the second object is not there...

Comment: i want to show the array in section 1 [array count] an section 0 for 2 different custom cells. so is section 0 accessing the array?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with you is that you have not initialized `temp` array. You have just declared it by name and assigning value. `NSArray *temp = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];`

So at that point, your `temp` array doesn't fill and it results, your `hostArray` doesn't fill too.
As far as my point of view, for this reason, you get this error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI       objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'`

So try this solution of `alloc init` `temp` array...Hope it may solve your issue...:)